# Why order data has deleted after updating the order "status" in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have written my application in Spring boot.

In this application, the orders placed by the user, have "status". The administrator have to change the status when these orders will ready.
But after changing the status, the orders data are being deleted.

How can i prevent the deletion of orders?

Here is code of "Order Controller":

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/order")
public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
    private OrderService OrderService;
    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private CartItemService cartItemService;

    @Autowired
    private ShoppingCartService shoppingCartService;

    @RequestMapping("/orderInfo")
    public String orderInfo(@RequestParam("id") Long id, Model model, Principal principal) {

        Order order = OrderService.findOne(id);


        model.addAttribute("order", order);

        return "orderInfo";
    }



    @RequestMapping(value="/orderUpdate", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateOrderPost(@ModelAttribute("order") Order order, Model model, Principal principal,  HttpServletRequest request) {
        User user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());
        ShoppingCart shoppingCart = user.getShoppingCart();
        List<CartItem> cartItemList = cartItemService.findByShoppingCart(shoppingCart);
        model.addAttribute("order", order);
        model.addAttribute("cartItemList", cartItemList);
        model.addAttribute("shoppingCart", shoppingCart);
        orderService.save(order);


    return "redirect:/order/orderList";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/orderUpdate")
    public String updateOrder(@RequestParam("id") Long id, Model model) {
        Order order = orderService.findOne(id);
        model.addAttribute("order", order);

        return "orderUpdate";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/orderList")
    public String orderList(Model model) {
        List<Order> orderList = OrderService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("orderList", orderList);     
        return "orderList";

    }

}
```

Comment: What is wrong with code above? I.e. what did you expect it to do?

Comment: It looks as if from the updated data it leaves only the data that has been updated and the rest has been deleted

Comment: my guess is that when you make a request to update the data, you only send the status field from client to the controller and spring maps the field to order object. Then, you persist this order directly to the database. The field that is missing when you persists will be saved as missing when you use ORM. You should not mix up Entity and DTO together.

Comment: So, what I need to do ?